# Event Viewer is "Level = Critical, Source = Kernel-Power, Event ID = 41, Task Category = 63"

Tags: windows-7

My computer reboots when I play league of legends, but only some games... i look in viewer events and i find this error:

```
Event Viewer is "Level = Critical, Source = Kernel-Power, Event ID = 41, Task Category = 63"

General:

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

DETALILS:

- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power 
   [ Guid]  {331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4} 

   EventID 41 

   Version 2 

   Level 1 

   Task 63 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8000000000000002 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-04-18T08:09:44.119206300Z 

   EventRecordID 12226 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  4 
   [ ThreadID]  8 

   Channel System 

   Computer Jordi-PC 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 


- EventData 

  BugcheckCode 0  
  BugcheckParameter1 0x0  
  BugcheckParameter2 0x0  
  BugcheckParameter3 0x0  
  BugcheckParameter4 0x0  
  SleepInProgress false  
  PowerButtonTimestamp 130422821525405351
```

What can I do to prevent this error?

Comment: check tis KB article and try all steps under scenario 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: What are the hardware specifications?

Comment: any idea? please